# How to make the firebase function synchronous?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the code of javascript function which again call the firebase database for checking the availability of the particular contact number, But this function did not working may be because of asynchronous behavior of firebase. Please Help, I am very new to firebase.

```
function check_number(){

  var contact = document.getElementById("check_contact").value;

  var i =0;

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Phone").orderByKey(); 

        ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot){

              snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){

                var key = childSnapshot.key;

                if (key == contact){
                  i = 1;
                }

              });

              if (i == 1){
                alert("found");
              }else{
                alert("not found");
              }

          });

     //alert("hey");
}
```

Calling the above function from the below form

```
        <form  onsubmit="check_number()" >
          <input type="number" id = "check_contact" />
          <input type="submit" value="Check" id="submit" >
        </form>
```

if I uncomment the alert("hey") the code works, else it doesnt.

Comment: Are the global variables intentional?

Comment: are u asking about the variable **contact**?

Comment: `contact` and `key`

Comment: No they are not intentional, they are local by the way. put  **var** with them if you want.

Comment: @SachinTanwar What exactly isnt working? At first look there is nothing wrong with your function. It could be the way you are calling it. Please add more details

Comment: Don't make it synchronous. Learn to work with asynchronous code instead.

Comment: I just want compare a contact with the data of firebase which contain the existing contact numbers. But not getting any way to do so , neither synchronously nor asynchronously . Please Help

Comment: When there is an alert box **alert("hey")**, the alert box wait for a response from user and in that time firebase function completes its execution and therefore code works synchronously, But without that alert box the function **check_number** did not wait for firebase function to execute synchronously and therefore code does not work. Is there any solution to make code works without using that alert **alert("hey")**